# Does time of adding new content makes sense for SE

Tags: search-engines

Does time, new content is added, makes sense for search engines ?

For example - between 9:00 and 18:00, or at 23:00, or at 1:00 ?

**Update 1:**

I rephrase my question, to better reflect, what i mean:

Does search engine makes an assumption about what the website is, based on time of day, new content is added. E.g. when new content is added between 9:00 and 18:00 - this is possible a corporation with fixed working time. When new content appears at random time of day, this is possible a person.

Answering my own question, i think, such an differentiation is not useful. But, who knows ...

Comment: What do you mean "make sense"?

Answer (score 1):

If new content is added to your website on regular basis it will be crawled on a regular basis. It is possible to set some preferences in your [Google webmaster tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) account.

About your question: If it is unique content and unrelated to for example a certain news event or trend it won't matter when its added. However, if you are adding content that is similar to content that appears on other websites it is, when it comes to your SERP positions, important that you content is crawled before the similar content on another website. This as your content will be considered the source and the rest as (partial)duplicates. How to handle a situation like that might be a whole different question and I am not sure if it is what you meant...

Comment: This is not, what i meant, but it is also useful. Thanks.

Comment: See update 1. I rephrased my question.

Answer (score 0):

Search engines crawl your site at whatever time suits them. It's best to add the content when your audience will see it. Then they might link to it from their blogs or twitter. Then your SE ranking will increase.